# Change Magento's Upsell Slider to use Related Products

Tags: php, magento

I have a client who has accidentally added the products in the Related Products section rather than the Upsell Section. I have a file named upsell_slider.phtml that spits out the following:

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
<div class="box-collateral box-up-sell upsell-slider">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Fashion Statement') ?></h2>
    <?php  $this->setColumnCount(4); // uncomment this line if you want to have another number of columns. also can be changed in layout ?>
    <?php $this->resetItemsIterator(); ?>
    <?php
        $products_count = 0;
        while($this->getIterableItem()){
            $products_count++;
        }
    ?>
    <div <?php if ($products_count > 1): ?>id="block-upsell-slider"<?php else:?> class="no-slider" <?php endif; ?>>
    <ul class="products-grid carousel-ul" id="upsell-product-table">
    <?php $this->resetItemsIterator(); while ($_item=$this->getIterableItem()) : ?>
        <li class="item grid_3 alpha">
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(420, null); ?>" <?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptions/Retina')->getRetinaData('upsell', $_item); ?> alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
            <div class="product-details">
                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <?php if ($products_count > 1): ?>
    <div class = 'next'></div>
    <div class = 'prev unselectable'></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      /* Upsell Block Slider */
      if(jQuery('#block-upsell-slider').length) {
          jQuery('#block-upsell-slider').iosSlider({
           responsiveSlideWidth: true,
           snapToChildren: true,
           desktopClickDrag: true,
           infiniteSlider: true,
           /* navSlideSelector: '.sliderNavi .naviItem', */
           navNextSelector: '.box-up-sell .next',
           navPrevSelector: '.box-up-sell .prev'
         });
     }

     function upsell_set_height(){
        var upsell_height = 0;
        jQuery('#block-upsell-slider li.item').each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).height() > upsell_height){
                upsell_height = jQuery(this).height();
            }
        })
        jQuery('#block-upsell-slider').css('min-height', upsell_height+2);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        upsell_set_height();
    }, 1000);
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){upsell_set_height();});
     /* Upsell Block Slider */
</script> 
<?php endif ?>
```

And I can't for the life of me get it to look at the related products, rather than the upsell products.

Comment: On which page you are calling upsell_slider.phtml?

Comment: on catalog.xml, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a better solution. You can transform the related products in upsells with one query.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_link` SET `link_type_id` = 4 WHERE `link_type_id` = 1;
```

Note. This will make move all the related products to upsells.
...and back up the table before trying it.

Comment: It effected 28 rows, but I can't see a change in any products?

Comment: @themartin This is strange. I had the same issue with a client in the past and this solved my issue.

Comment: Looking in the database. It definitely seems like the right thing. I'm fairly new to magento, so I'll reindex everything and see if that helps. Any other cache-type things I should look out for?

Comment: Did a re-index, still no dice. Database is showing how I'd expect, all set to '4' ?

Comment: @themartin, In this case, restore your table and ignore my answer. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: No, I think you've got it right. I'm fairly sure my developer is lying about which is the correct database. Thanks!